# Orange3 RAM requirement for large data set

Tags: python, memory, ram, orange

I am working with a data set (.csv file) of ~ 4.80 GB. While I have no problem 
reading it into a pandas data frame, in Orange3 it is not possible. I quickly run out of RAM (I have 16 GB). Together with swap, it is ~24 GB.

Does anyone have a rule of thumb how much RAM is required in Orange based on  the size of the data set on disk?

Comment: I don't think any Orange widget will handle datasets of that scale. You're not missing out. :D